# Powershell stuck in infinite loop

Tags: powershell, infinite-loop

I have powershell code that takes an array, goes through each element and updates an SQL database on another server.

It seems to get stuck in the following code

```
do{
    try{
        $cmd_update = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql_update,$conn_update)
        $found = $cmd_update.ExecuteNonQuery()   
        $num_moved=$num_moved+1
        $timestamp = Get-Date
        Add-Content D:\Script\Output_SCHOOLS_Default_Group.log "Moving $ip, SEP version $sep_version to $group_name, $timestamp`r" 
        Write-host Moving $ip, SEP version $sep_version to $group_name, $timestamp
        $transactionComplete = $true
    } 
    catch{
        $transactionComplete = $false
    }
} until ($transactionComplete)
```

It will stay in this look until $transactionComplete, which may never happen, depending on system bottlenecks.

How do I exit the look if 1 minute has passed and $transactionComplete is still false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this before the loop:

```
$start = Get-Date
```

And put this at the end of the catch block:

```
if (((Get-Date)-$start).TotalMinutes -gt 1) {
    $transactionComplete = $true
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't it be $transactionComplete = $true, because that is the condition to exit the loop?

Comment: Right you are. It also needs to go in Catch... Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can introduce one more condition that checks if the total time spent executing is more than one minute.

For example,

```
$MaxTime = new-timespan -Minutes 1
$StopWatch = [Diagnostics.StopWatch]::StartNew()
do{                
    try{    
        $cmd_update = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($sql_update,$conn_update)
        $found = $cmd_update.ExecuteNonQuery()   
        $num_moved=$num_moved+1  
        $timestamp = Get-Date                        
        Add-Content D:\Script\Output_SCHOOLS_Default_Group.log "Moving $ip, SEP version $sep_version to $group_name, $timestamp`r" 
        Write-host Moving $ip, SEP version $sep_version to $group_name, $timestamp
        $transactionComplete = $true
    } 
    catch{
        $transactionComplete = $false
    }
} until ($transactionComplete -or (-not $StopWatch.Elapsed))
```